# Как лучше хранить много текстовых данных в Android?

Tags: android, java

Нужно сделать приложение, в котором должно быть много текстовых данных, около 120 string`ов. Каждый "пункт" должен  иметь несколько строк, например: id, name, question. Первое, что пришло в голову это засовывать строки в HashMap и там их по ключу вытаскивать. Еще в голову пришла идея с SQLite, засовывать данные туда, а потом вытаскивать. С использованием готовых БД SQLite в андроид все плохо, только через костыли (созданием новой и перезаписыванием в нее и т.д.) . Так вот вопрос, как сделать лучше? Может есть какие-то другие функции, которые мне сильно помогут, но я о них не знаю?

Comment: в андроиде вполне нормально можно работать с БД без всяких костылей

Comment: Костыль заключается в использовании уже готовой БД, с созданием новой и ее заполнения, там проблем нет.

Comment: @Vlad161 нет там костыля. Даже на hashcode уже спрашивали про это. Использовать уже готовую БД не проблема (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данные то статичные или динамически подгружаются? 
Если статичны, то можно просто в файле хранить xml/json.

Если динамично подгружаются, то я бы SQLite рекомендовал.

Comment: Выберу для себя json, Спасибо!